# How to identify if the submitted value came from the autocomplete script?

Tags: php, mysql

In my form there is a textbox and submit button. When a user starts typing, after the 3rd letter the autocomplete script does it's magic.

There are two possibilities.

1. The user types a word, there are matches and he clicks on one match. This selected match is added to the textbox and then hits the submit button.
2. The user types a word, there/there are not matches but he decides to hit the submit button without selecting one of the suggested.

My question is how can I identify whether he hit the button in case 1 or in case 2.

**rpc.php** is the file that looks for suggested values through the mySQL.

A solution is to check the string if there is on the database but I do not want this.

Another solution is to transform the jQuery script and php code that shows the product name and instead of putting the product in the textbox, it should take him to the results page. This solves my problem also.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {

    $("#s").autocomplete("rpc.php", {
        width: 250,
        selectFirst: false,
        minChars: 3,
        scroll:true,
matchContains: true,

        scrollHeight: 250
    });

});
</script>

<form method="get" action=".php">
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" class="inputsearch">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: rpc.php must be returning an array for the autocomplete to use, look through that array, and if the submitted word is in the array, then you're good to go (whether it was filled in w the autocomplete or typed in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use autocomplete's `change` method to set a flag in the form, eg

```
/// Create an hidden element to store the flag value,
/// 1 for AC used, 0 for user entered
var flag = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden")
                       .attr("name", "ac_flag")
                       .val(0);

// append flag to form
$("form").append(flag);

$("#s").autocomplete("rpc.php", {
    change: function(event, ui) {
        flag.val(ui.item != null ? 1 : 0);
    },
    // and the rest
});
```

The "change" event fires when the value in the text field changes. When an AC item is chosen `ui.item` will contain an object reference to the selected item from the list. If no selection was made, ie the user simply entered text, `ui.item` will be null.

Your form handler can then check for `$_GET['ac_flag']` to determine whether or not the value came from the autocomplete list.

Quick mockup example here - http://jsfiddle.net/9GQgh/

Comment: Hi, can you explain it to me. Also I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to modify the `autocomplete` plugin itself to set a flag when the user chooses a value from it, and clear it when the user modifies their selection.  The flag could be anywhere, but for the sake of simplicity I'd suggest a hidden form field, like:

```
<form method="get" action=".php">
    <input type="text" name="s" id="s" class="inputsearch">
    <input type="hidden" id="flag" name="inputCameFromAutocomplete" value="false">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

So in the `autocomplete` plugin, when the user makes a selection, you could add something like:

```
$("#flag").val("true");
```

If you wanted to you could make the id/selector of the flag element part of the plugin config/options so that it is more reusable.

You would also want to do something like:

```
$("#s").keypress(function() {
    $("#flag").val("false");
});
```

...as part of your initial setup, so that the flag is reset whenever the user manually types something into the field.

Comment: This would result in a `false` flag even if the user typed in `iphone case black`, which presumably is fine to use in the MySQL query.... though it's unclear from the OP whether this would be undesired or desired.

Comment: If the user typed luckily `iphone case black` the system has to identify it as a user entry.

Comment: @Peter - Yes, the only way to avoid that would be to iterate through the last set of suggestions on submit to see if it contains a value that exactly matches the input.  Which would probably also have to be done as an internal modification of the autocomplete plugin.

Comment: Another approach is if the user click on the suggested name, then it will not place it into the textbox but take him there. (the link will be coded in the rpc.php is not a deal). I tried it but it place it in the textbox. (you have to right click open in new tab to do it as I want)

Comment: @JPampos - This should work for you then.  If the user types `iphone case black` it will be counted as user-input.  If they choose it from the autocomplete dialog then it will be counted as an autocomplete selection.  Taking the user automatically to a link will also work, but it removes the user's ability to manually edit an autocomplete suggestion after selecting it.

Comment: @aroth So I guess the best solution is as I suggested in my previous comment. Is this possible?

Comment: @JPampos - Yes, entirely possible.  You just need to catch/hook into the selection event, as above, and instead of setting the flag just post to the correct URL.  The basic flow is pretty much identical.

Comment: Aroth I updated entirely my question for better understanding. I have tried your example but I always get a false value on the hidden value. This is because the user will always type in the textbox something for the suggest list to appear. The list appears on the 3rd typed letter. Also can we return it to true if the textbox is blank? He may delete what he typed to start again. How does this changes your code?